# Fourier expand with half integer

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-series

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a contious function. Then we have the Fourier series of $f$:

$$f(x) \sim \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\sin(n\pi x)$$
with $\displaystyle a_n = 2 \int_0^1 f(z)\sin(n\pi z)dz.$

Can we get the expandation

$$f(x) \sim \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n \sin  \left(n+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\pi x $$

If yes, how to get the coefficent $b_n$. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried to calculate $\int_0^1g_n(x)g_m(x)\ dx$ and $\int_0^1f(x)g_n(x)\ dx$ where $g_n(x)=\sin[(n+1/2)\pi x]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this can happen if you're trying to solve a boundary value problem
$$\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$$
$$y(0,t)=0$$
$$y^{\prime}(1,t)=0$$
$$y(x,0)=f(x)$$
So your eigenfunctions are now
$$y_n(x,t)=\sin\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi xe^{-\left(n+\frac12\right)^2\pi^2t}$$
The eignefunctions are orthogonal because they are the solutions to a Sturm-Liouville eigenvalue problem, but we can check that if $n\ne m$ then
$$\begin{align}\int_0^1\sin\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi x\sin\left(m+\frac12\right)\pi x\,dx&=\frac12\int_0^1\left[\cos(n-m)\pi x-\cos(n+m+1)\pi x\right]dx\\
&=\frac12\left[\frac{\sin(n-m)\pi x}{(n-m)\pi}-\frac{\sin(n+m+1)\pi x}{(n+m+1)\pi}\right]_0^1\\
&=0\end{align}$$
And
$$\begin{align}\int_0^1\sin^2\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi x\,dx&=\frac12\int_0^1\left[1-\cos(2n+1)\pi x\right]dx\\
&=\frac12\left[x-\frac{\sin(2n+1)\pi x}{(2n+1)\pi}\right]_0^1=\frac12\end{align}$$
So we can see that
$$b_n=2\int_0^1f(x)\sin\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi x\,dx$$